# visual studio git: terminal prompts disabled

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio

I cloned a **VSTS (NOT GitHub)** repository with bash on windows using URL like https://myproj.visualstudio.com/repo and now I'd like to be able to use in-built **VS2017** git window for my work, however when I do say **Pull** I get a window asking for my username/password and after I provide them I get this error:

```
Git failed with a fatal error.
could not read Username for 'https://myproj.visualstudio.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

which doesn't make any sense to me, I'm still able to do everything from git bash, I was also able to use VS2017 in-built window until today (we had some accounts migration which I'm not aware of the details), I tried relogging everywhere (at least what I'm aware of) and reinstalling git/visual studio, but still no success. All the suggestions I was able to find are either related to GitHub or suggest me to use **ssh**, which I don't want to, because my colleagues still have it working quite fine with **https** as before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to delete contents of this file:
C:\Users\my_user\.ssh\known_hosts
I didn't see it documented anywhere, it was just one of my numerous random attempts to fix things

Comment: What has you hostsfile to do with that? I highly doubt it.

Comment: Does not work for me. I doubt it, too.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for me was to download and install TortoiseGit and then get a repository cloned through its credential manager. Afterwards, I connected to the repository within Visual Studio 2017 as a local repository.

In this approach we have to use TortoiseGit for all repo operations.

Better to try these instructions, which completely resolved my issue: 
https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/176/how-to-fix-fatal-error-with-git-in-visual-studio-2017

Comment: Bumping for the Link to the instructions. That worked for me.

Comment: tried several times to configure wincred. My last attempt was to go to Tortoise/Git menu (root), and go to edit global gitconfig. There in helpers, I replaced manager (credential manager) by wincred (the other credential manager that seems to work fine), and it worked!! finally!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer for my case:

I had to add a username to my repo URLs. "https://user@repo..." instead of "https://repo...".

Explanation:

I had cloned a main repo but could not update the submodules of that repo because the username was missing inside the .gitmodules file.

A PAT token was taken automatically in my corporate network by single sign on authentication, but that  PAT token did not work without username.

The error message was a little misleading, also the vscode IDE asked for a username and password but I did not realize. With a username given, the PAT token of my single sign on worked.